# Unable to read file from HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to read files from HDFS. I am using the following code:

```
val sam = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://localhost:9000"+inputFolder,4)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://localhost, expected: hdfs://localhost:9000
```

I had referenced this question for adding the URI in my file path:
[Cannot Read a file from HDFS using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478096/cannot-read-a-file-from-hdfs-using-spark)

But I am still not able to read the file due t the above error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What is `inputFolder?`

Comment: It's a string variable for path inside the HDFS...

Comment: I'm confused about the error, says you used `hdfs://localhost`, but `expected: hdfs://localhost:9000`, and that is what your code already is using. Are you sure HDFS is running and is on port 9000 and is on your localhost?

Comment: yes I checked it in core-site.xml file

Comment: and what about `sc.wholeTextFiles(inputFolder,4)`?

Comment: Then it errors out file not found...which is ok since it is in HDFS

Comment: I dont understand. Files are not located in inputFolder?

Comment: inputFolder is a path in HDFS file system...if I use it like `sc.wholeTextFiles(inputFolder,4)` then spark would search in the local file system rather than HDFS and so will not find this path.

Comment: It looks like you dont have specified HADOOP_CONF_DIR check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27301040/2715438)

Comment: where should I define this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check adding winutils.exe in your system and setting a environment variable for the same . Spark needs winutils.exe to do hdfs operations.

Answer (score 0):

Try using IP instead of localhost