# How to open a parquet file in HDFS with Python?

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

I am looking to read a parquet file that is stored in HDFS and I am using Python to do this. I have this code below but it does not open the files in HDFS.  Can you help me change the code to do this?

```
sc = spark.sparkContext

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.parquet('path-to-file/commentClusters.parquet')
```

Also, I am looking to save the Dataframe as a CSV file as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a try with

```
sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs://<host:port>/path-to-file/commentClusters.parquet")
```

To find out the host and port, just search for the file core-site.xml and look for xml element fs.defaultFS (e.g. $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml)

To make it simple, try

```
sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs:////path-to-file/commentClusters.parquet")
```

or

```
sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs:/path-to-file/commentClusters.parquet")
```

Referring [Cannot Read a file from HDFS using Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478096/cannot-read-a-file-from-hdfs-using-spark)

To save as csv, try

```
df_result.write.csv(path=res_path) # possible options: header=True, compression='gzip'
```