# How to read data from HDFS using spark streaming?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(1000));
```

My HDFS directory contains json files

Comment: I hope this stackoverflow question helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478096/cannot-read-a-file-from-hdfs-using-spark

Comment: @SatishT That question isn't Spark *Streaming*

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ ... https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-sources

Answer (score 2):

You can use `textFileStream` to read it as a text file and convert it later.

```
val dstream = ssc.textFileStream("path to hdfs directory")
```

This gives you `DStream[Strings]` which is a collection of `RDD[String]`

Then you can get an RDD for each interval of time as

```
dstream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  //now apply a transformation or anything with the each rdd
 spark.read.json(rdd) // to change it to dataframe
})

scc.start()             // Start the computation
ssc.awaitTermination()   // Wait for the computation to terminate
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I am sorry I am not so good in java, But won't be much difference with compared to this one.